When awk becomes too cumbersome, what is the next classic Unix tool to consider to deal with text transformation?
Awk is invaluable for many purposes where text filter logic spans multiple lines and you need to maintain state (unlike grep and sed), but as I'm finding lately there may be cases where you need something more flexible (at the cost of simplicity).
What would come next in the complexity of continuum using Unix's "do one thing well" suite of tools?
    cat in.txt | grep foo                                                       | tee out.txt
    cat in.txt | grep -e foo -e bar                                             | tee out.txt
    cat in.txt | sed 's/(foo|bar)/corrected/'                                   | tee out.txt
    cat in.txt | awk 'BEGIN{ myvar=0 } /foo/{ myvar += 1} END{ print myvar}'    | tee out.txt
    cat in.txt | ????                                                           | tee out.txt


What is the next "classic" unix-approach/tool handled for the next phase of the continuum of complexity?

Would it be a hand-written compiler using bash's readline?
While Perl can do it, I read somewhere that that is a departure from the unix philosophy of do one thing well.
I've heard of lex/yacc, flex/bison but haven't used them. They seem like a significant step up.


Here is my opinion about this question:
lex/yacc, flex/bison are mostly lexical analyzer/parser(s) and expect as input text in specific language. And provide as output C, Java, C++, etc. So for me they are not exactly what you search for.
awk is really very powerful language. Let me demonstrate based on your examples:
grep foo in.txt = awk '/foo/' in.txt
grep -e foo -e bar in.txt = awk '/foo|bar/' in.txt
sed 's/(foo|bar)/corrected/' in.txt = awk '{gsub(/foo|bar/,"corrected");}1' in.txt

So you can use it for (probably) everywhere. But you should learn it well. Yes, sometimes the constructions are not very readable, but after time will be fine :)
If you want something very powerful you can start learning python. This can be named as next point in the list. But python can be quite complicated and (for me also quite) unreadable.
About your use of cat please read this Q/A. Also check this discussion.

I'm not sure python can be considered any more of a "classic Unix tool" than perl or is any less of a "departure from the unix philosophy of do one thing well". and, like perl but unlike awk, it's not a mandatory POSIX tool and so if you're considering python you may as well also consider perl, ruby, etc. as they all fall into the same category of non-POSIX general-purpose tools which is very different from awk as a mandatory POSIX text-processing tool. Nothing against python, I use it frequently, it just isn't what I'd consider to be 'the next "classic" unix-approach/tool' the OP asked about.

@EdMorton While not a mandatory POSIX tool Python does have a couple of major advantages:

It is available for just about everything so python scripts can work everywhere.
You can construct commented regular expressions by using the re.VERBOSE flag - this is a major advantage to me as you can document what your re is trying to do.


@SteveBarnes major advantages over what - perl or ruby or something else? The OP isn't asking 'which tool has some advantages over awk', they're asking which tool is 'the next "classic" unix-approach/tool' and, while I personally prefer python over perl or ruby, I'm just saying "python" isn't the obvious answer for the reasons I stated despite it having some functionality not present in awk. I don't think there IS a clear answer to the OPs question - if not awk, the right tool depends on what the OP actually wants to do and so might be mlr, or xmlstarlet, or jq, or yq or something different.

Regarding re.VERBOSE -  I see an example of that at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/verbose-in-python-regex/ and you can do almost exactly the same thing in awk or any other tool by defining the regexp as a series of arguments to sprintf("%s%s%s%s%s",...) written on separate lines. I can't show that in a comment so ask a question if you'd like to see it but, again, the question isn't whether or not python has some functionality not present in awk, it's whether or not python (or perl or ruby) is 'THE next "classic" unix-approach/tool' as it exhibits 'the unix philosophy of do one thing well'.

Regarding "It is available for just about everything so python scripts can work everywhere" - "just about everything" != "everywhere". Many of us work in environments where, due to corporate policy for example, the only tools we have available are the mandatory POSIX tools but if you work in an environment where you do have or can install python then you almost certainly have or can install perl too so availability wouldn't be a reason to favor python over perl as 'the next "classic" unix-approach/tool'.

I understand "classic unix tool" is vague. After reading the excellent book "Unix: A history and a memoir" it seems to me like yacc is what the gods like Brian Kernighan turned to next, putting more and more of the specification in the hands of the user. I vaguely recall the original context of my question was when I was finding it too cumbersome to parse yml/json/xml with awk but all these answers are good ones.
